# fileno() not available?

Tags: c, gcc, posix, c99

I am trying to use the posix function `isatty()` in my C code, to tell if the output is being redirected. However, to do this I need a file descriptor, and from my research it looks like `fileno()` is no longer included with `stdio.h`. Are there any alternative methods of getting a file descriptor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to know if output is being redirected, you can use:

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
  error("redirect output.");
```

`STDOUT_FILENO` is generally 1.

Comment: I didn't know that. This works better for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 5):

It's still there, but you may have to explicitly turn on POSIX features.  In particular, under Linux, `fileno` is only available if POSIX or XOPEN features are enabled.  From the `fileno(3)` manpage:

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
> fileno(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
> ```

So, compile with `-D_POSIX_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 3):

[`fileno()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html) is still the POSIX-standard way of getting the file descriptor associated with a file stream.

What compilation options are you using, on which platform(s)?  Are you enabling the POSIX extensions?

```
gcc -std=gnu99 ...
```

This should make `fileno()` visible.  (Using `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic` may make them invisible.)

Alternatively, add a variation on this stanza to your code, or put it in a header and include that at the start of your code:

```
#ifndef JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H
#define JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H

/*
** Include this file before including system headers.  By default, with
** C99 support from the compiler, it requests POSIX 2001 support.  With
** C89 support only, it requests POSIX 1997 support.  Override the
** default behaviour by setting either _XOPEN_SOURCE or _POSIX_C_SOURCE.
*/

/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L */
/* _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 is loosely equivalent to _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L */

#if !defined(_XOPEN_SOURCE) && !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE)
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600   /* SUS v3, POSIX 1003.1 2004 (POSIX 2001 + Corrigenda) */
#else
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500   /* SUS v2, POSIX 1003.1 1997 */
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */
#endif /* !_XOPEN_SOURCE && !_POSIX_C_SOURCE */

#endif /* JLSS_ID_POSIXVER_H */
```

For my purposes, `_XOPEN_SOURCE` set to 600 is better than 700; it works out of the box on more machine types.  You may be able to use 700.  I keep this in a file `posixver.h` and my code starts

```
#include "posixver.h"
```

before any of the system headers.  This allows me to change the rules (600 to 700, for example) centrally and I only need to recompile, not edit every source file.